# Powershell - Loop run console app >Wait for Ctrl+c

Tags: powershell, console-application

I have a windows console app that currently runs to process some files, at the end of the run, if successful, it starts a windows service and I get the output > xxx service is now running, press control_c to exit.

The console app looks at a config file to pull some parameters, I need to be able to re-run this multiple times while changing the parameters in the config file first. To do this manually I'd do the following:

- change config file
- run the app from powershell
- wait for the message above to appear
- click ctrl + c to terminate
- change config file and run again

I thought it makes sense to automate this in a PS script where I can just pass the config values for all the runs, then the script loops through the values, edit the config file and run the exe.

Issue I have is the loop gets "stuck" at first run because the application is waiting for the ctrl+c command so never progresses through the loop.

what I have at the moment looks like this:

```
foreach ($dt in $datesarr)
{
    ##edit config values with stuff in $dt       
    $output=(<path to app here>)    
    while ($output[-1] -notlike "*Control-C*")
        {
            Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
        }

}
```

problem I have is the script never reaches the while loop as it's just stuck after running the app awaiting for ctrl + c... What I want it to do is launch the app, wait for it to get to the ctrl + c bit then exit the loop and pick the second value in the parameter.

Any thoughts would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: You might run things in parallel (in another thread) and check asynchronously whether the service ([`get-service`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-service)) is running and e.g. close the related window, assuming that you are able to identify it (more details about the "app" are required to help you with this).

Comment: running in parallel is not an option unfortunately due to nature of the app. What extra info do you need to help with this?

Comment: Let's start with the name? Is it a known app? (If it is a custom app, how is it created?) Does it open a new console? (Where is the `xxx service is now running` shown?) What is the name of the service? See also [how to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) This is appears to me as a strange limitation/behavior of the application (not PowerShell).

Comment: It is a custom application, developed in .net by an external vendor, and yes I agree the limitation is with the app itself rather than powershell. 
The xxx service is now running is the output the app sends when ran via powersell\cmd. basically as described, to run manually we launch ps, and run the app ./app.exe which throws the output mentioned above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following approach, which is based on direct use of the following, closely related .NET APIs:

- [`System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo)
- [`System.Diagnostics.Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Diagnostics.Process)

Instead of trying to programmatically press Ctrl-C, the process associated with the external program is simply *killed* (terminated).

```
# Remove the next line if you don't want to see verbose output.
$VerbosePreference = 'Continue'

$psi = [System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo] @{
  UseShellExecute = $false
  WindowStyle = 'Hidden'
  FileName = '<path to app here>'
  Arguments = '<arguments string here>'  # only if args must be passed
  RedirectStandardOutput = $true
  RedirectStandardError = $true  # optional - if you also want to examine stderr
}

Write-Verbose "Launching $($psi.FileName)..."
$ps = [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start($psi)

Write-Verbose "Waiting for launched process $($ps.Id) to output the line of interest..."
$found = $false
while (
  -not $ps.HasExited -and
  -not ($found = ($line = $ps.StandardOutput.ReadLine()) -match 'Control-C')
) {
  Write-Verbose "Stdout line received: $line"
}

if ($found) {
  Write-Verbose  "Line of interest received; terminating process $($ps.Id)."
  # Note: If the process has already terminated, this will be a no-op.
  #       .Kill() kills only the target process itself.
  #       In .NET Core / .NET 5+, you can use .Kill($true) to also
  #       kill descendants of the process, i.e. all processes launched
  #       by it, directly and via its children.
  $ps.Kill() 
} else {
  Write-Error "Process $($ps.Id) terminated before producing the expected output."
}
$ps.Dispose()
```

Comment: Thank you! This has worked like a charm :) 
only comment (due to me being awful at PS), the "term" I was looking for was Control+C, seems Match didn't like that but I looked for another "clue" in the output and this has worked. THank you very much!

Comment: Glad to hear it, @user7415753; my pleasure. You could use `-match 'Control\+C'` - since  [`-match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match) is regex-based, the metacharacter `+` must be escaped; `-like '*Control+C*'`, as in your original approach works too.